# Breadth-first search algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, queue, breadth-first-search

Like a previous problem I had earlier, I am trying to create a breadth-first search algorithm that takes a graph and outputs the vertex visit order. It takes an adjacency matrix (representing the graph) as its input and here is what I have so far.

```
import sys
import Queue

# Input has to be adjacency matrix or list
graphAL2 = {0 : [1,2,3],
        1 : [0,3,4],
        2 : [0,4,5],
        3 : [0,1,5],
        4 : [1,2],
        5 : [2,3] }

# NEED TO FIX:
# - Final graphAL2v print is only displaying key values as 1, not iterating
# through graph and visiting each vertex

def main():
    count = 0
    graphAL2v = {}

    for key, value in graphAL2.items():
        graphAL2v[key] = 0

    print(graphAL2v)

    for key in graphAL2v: # each vertex v in V
        if graphAL2v[key] == 0: # is marked with 0
            bfs(key, count, graphAL2, graphAL2v)
    print(graphAL2v)

def bfs(v, count, graphal, graphv):
    count = count + 1
    print('Visiting', v)

    # Mark v with count and initialize queue with v
    graphv[v] = count
    visited = Queue.Queue()

    while not visited.empty(): #queue not empty:
        print('queue is not empty')
        for element in graphal[v]: # each vertex w in V adjacent to front vertex
            if element == 0:
                count = count + 1
                # mark w with count
                graphal[v] = count
                visited.put()
        visited.get()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

The problem that I am running into is that my output

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
('Visiting', 0)
('Visiting', 1)
('Visiting', 2)
('Visiting', 3)
('Visiting', 4)
('Visiting', 5)
{0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}
```

displays the visit order as 1 for all vertices in the list when it should be displaying the visit order as a different number for each vertex as it traverses the "graph." I believe that this error is stemming from within the while loop of the bfs() function. Any suggestions for trying to fix the code so I can achieve the desired output? I'm also not that familiar with queues in Python so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The program is not recursive (or did I miss it?)

Comment: @amit you're right. I'm not sure why I said recursive when it's clearly not. My mind must be melted from working on this all day

Comment: What's the smallest graph that displays the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of issues in your code -

1. First of all, you are never putting anything in the Queue that you create, so its always empty, you need to put the `v` inside the queue before the `while` loop , that is the starting point.
2. Secondly, in the `for` loop, you are checking `element == 0` , which is wrong, you need to check if `graphv[element] == 0` , that is whether the element has been already visited or not.
3. Thirdly, in the `for` loop, you need to set `graphv[element] = count` , that signifies that you vivisted `element` .
4. You are not putting anything inside the queue with - `visited.put()` , you need to pass the element to put inside the Queue as parameter.
5. When getting back the element from the Queue, you need to assign it back to `v`, otherwise `v` would never change, `v` signifies the current element being iterated.

Example code -

```
import sys
import Queue

# Input has to be adjacency matrix or list
graphAL2 = {0 : [1,2,3],
        1 : [0,3,4],
        2 : [0,4,5],
        3 : [0,1,5],
        4 : [1,2],
        5 : [2,3] }

# NEED TO FIX:
# - Final graphAL2v print is only displaying key values as 1, not iterating
# through graph and visiting each vertex

def main():
    count = 0
    graphAL2v = {}

    for key, value in graphAL2.items():
        graphAL2v[key] = 0

    print(graphAL2v)

    for key in graphAL2v: # each vertex v in V
        if graphAL2v[key] == 0: # is marked with 0
            bfs(key, count, graphAL2, graphAL2v)
    print(graphAL2v)

def bfs(v, count, graphal, graphv):
    count = count + 1
    print('Visiting', v)

    # Mark v with count and initialize queue with v
    graphv[v] = count
    visited = Queue.Queue()
    visited.put(v)
    while not visited.empty(): #queue not empty:
        print('queue is not empty')
        for element in graphal[v]: # each vertex w in V adjacent to front vertex
            if graphv[element] == 0:
                count = count + 1
                # mark w with count
                graphv[element] = count
                visited.put(element)
        v = visited.get()
    return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

Demo (after above changes) -

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
Visiting 0
queue is not empty
queue is not empty
queue is not empty
queue is not empty
queue is not empty
queue is not empty
{0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6}
```

Comment: This is the answer. A further suggestion would be to avoid `Queue.Queue` (which is intended for synchronization in multi-threaded applications) and use `collections.deque` instead.

Comment: @Anand S Kumar Thank you very much! I always get confused with comparing elements in dictionaries and your explanations of the queue methods make so much sense. I'll keep this in mind for future problems!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the graph libraries that provide search algorithms, such as NetworkX:

```
from networkx import *
graphAL2 = {0 : [1,2,3],
        1 : [0,3,4],
        2 : [0,4,5],
        3 : [0,1,5],
        4 : [1,2],
        5 : [2,3] }

g = Graph()

# create graph
for node in graphAL2:
    g.add_node(node)
    for target_node in graphAL2[node]:
        g.add_edge(node, target_node)

print bfs_successors(g, 0)
```

This will get the successors of each node, exporting the search order from that should be a piece of cake.

Output:

```
{0: [1, 2, 3], 1: [4], 2: [5]}
```